# Pulling master from Github from a side branch

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm working on a separate branch from the master branch, and I wondering what will happen if I pull the latest changes from Github. Should I pull from the master branch or the side branch? If I pull from the side branch, will it just merge the updates with my new code in the side branch?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "side branch"; you should drop your own lingo and start using the same lingo as the rest of the community. It's just a branch. It might be a development branch, a feature branch or a topic branch, but "side branch" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @meagar type "man git-rebase". "side branch" IS a term used in that man page. Albeit not a popular term, it still used in places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to

1. fetch changes to `origin/master`
2. merge `origin/master` into your local `master` branch
3. merge your `master` branch into your feature branch

If your master hasn't changed you should:

```
git checkout master
git pull # fetches (step 1) and merges (step 2)
git checkout <my branch>
git merge master # (step 3)
```

If your local master has changed, `git pull` may cause merge conflicts that you will have to resolve. If you want to keep your history clean, you might consider `git pull --rebase` and/or rebasing your feature branch onto the newly merged master once steps 1 and 2 are complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you pull from a local branch, you have to specify what remote branch you want to pull from. So if you specify that you want to pull from the `master` remote branch, changes that happened on it will get merged in your local branch:

```
git pull <github-repo-url> master
```

Then to update your local master branch, check it out and run the same.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. My side branch has never been pushed to Github. I want to pull master and update both my local master and my side branch with the new code.

Comment: In that case the pull should work fine.  No matter which branch you are on.  If you cloned that repo, your master should be tracking the remote master and it will update the proper one.

Comment: do I need to specify what I'm pulling? `git pull master`

Comment: Depends from your configuration, but you'd probably want to go with `git pull origin master`